# How does passing parameters to a perl module when using it work?

Tags: perl

Here's an example of what I mean

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ qw( debug ) ];
```

So what is `+trace` in SOAP::Lite? I'm guessing it is part of a package scoped hash? I mean if I wanted to implement similar syntax into one of my modules how would I do it?

How would this work if I also needed to import symbols, e.g.

```
use Foo qw( some_function );
```

Would this work?

```
use Foo qw( some_function ) +option => 'bar';
```

would any additional magic be needed in the module that allows you to pass things like this?

*note: not sure I like the title of the question, feel free to reword*

Comment: You can probably see how `SOAP::Lite` does it by reading the source; `perldoc -m SOAP::Lite` is one way to do this.

Comment: @Keith reading the source doesn't bring all the understanding of asking... and results in coding by coincidence

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do `use Foo @args`, what happens behind the scenes is equivalent to this:

```
BEGIN { 
    require 'Foo.pm';
    Foo->import( @args );
};
```

So in this case, `use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ qw( debug ) ]` gets turned into an `import` call like this:

```
SOAP::Lite->import( '+trace' => [ 'debug' ] );
```

Precisely how one implements the `import` routine is up to the module author. Most modules use the standard `import` provided by `Exporter`, but you can put anything you want there and it will be executed at `use` time.

Comment: And with this understanding, you can try to make sense of SOAP::Lite::import()'s source code.